# Recursividad en c++

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber como puedo crear una funcion recursiva para leer los numeros desde 1 a N.

He tenido problemas para crear el codigo base lo cual podria pensar que N seria como un limite dado por el usuario y cuando se compare con el Numero 1 que va aumentando ahi deberia parar , y tambien como podria imprimir estos mismo numeros hasta donde el usuario seleccionó

Comment: "*He tenido problemas para crear el código base*". Si muestras dicho código, te podremos decir si tu enfoque es correcto y/o en qué falla.

Comment: Para leer los número de 1 a N, leer de ¿dónde? Expresa tu problema mejor, porque yo no sé lo qué estás pidiendo.

Comment: `f();` llama a `f();` si es `N` no llamará mas a `f();` etc...